# How to load tables and save tables from different .mat files and create new table dimension for each file

Tags: matlab, datatables, save, concatenation

I am using Matlab 2019 and I saved a large number of different tables with the same name, each in a .mat-file with a different name. I'd like to load them and save them in a new table together.

I need a table that has the same variables (variable1, variable2, variable3), and numbers but an additional dimension for the different .mat-files. I.e. in the dummy code below the size of the table allData should be: 2 x 3 x 2.

If I simply concatenate them like this [Results1.Inpts; Results2.Inpts], then the table is 4 x 3 and I cannot distinguish the data from the different files.

Also I have a large number of .mat-files, so I would like to automate it like done here (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/233745-loading-mat-files-with-same-variable-name), which I tried to do for my table below, but it didn't work.

Please find my dummy code below.

```
%% Create data and .mat files

clc;
clear;
close all;
format long;

Names = {'variable1','variable2','variable3'};
Numbers1 = [2, 3, 4; 3, 4, 5];
Numbers2 = [1, 4, 10; 2, 6, 3];

Inpts = array2table(Numbers1,'VariableNames',Names);
save('Results1.mat');
clear Inpts;

Inpts = array2table(Numbers2,'VariableNames',Names);
save('Results2.mat');

clear;

%% Analyse data

files = dir('*.mat');
allData = table(size(files));
for ii=1:length(files)
  aFileData = load(files(ii).name);
  allData{ii} = aFileData.Inpts;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add a column in each table before concatenation

```
allData = cell(numel(files),1); % Store the tables in a cell
for ii=1:length(files)
  aFileData = load(files(ii).name);
  % Add a column
  aFileData.FileName(:) = {files(ii).name};
  % Stick the modified table in the cell
  allData{ii} = aFileData.Inpts;
end
% Merge tables
allData = vertcat( allData{:} );
```

Comment: This creates a table with size 4 x 3 (in this case), which is exactly what I do NOT want (please see question above). I would need a table 2 x 3 x 3, where the last dimension stands for the different .mat-files.

Comment: @LenaH MATLAB tables are 2D... You should be able to do everything you want by indexing just an additional column (making your table tall rather than deep)

Comment: @Wolfie: Holy cow, you can say `aFileData.FileName(:) = <some scalar value>` even if the `.FileName` column doesn't exist yet? I've been mucking around with `repmat(...)` to accomplish this for years now!

Comment: BTW, I think you might be better off doing `= string(files(ii).name)` instead of ` {files(ii).name}` cellstr. Strings are typed and faster than cellstrs now, so I always use `string` arrays for textual columns when working with tables, and MathWorks recommends the same.

Comment: @AndrewJanke yeah nifty tip, as long as you've got at least one column to scale to :) some of my work is still tied to older MATLAB versions so I rarely consider strings for compatibility issues, but yeah your point is valid

Comment: @Wolfie ah right. Can you remove the last 2 lines in your reply? Then I can just use the cell, e.g. allInpts{1}.variable1 etc.

Comment: @Lena yeah you can do just that if it's your preferred option!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do a 3-dimensional array with the third dimension corresponding to files, you can't use a `table`, because tables are inherently two-dimensional. Instead, convert your table data back to a matrix after reading it, and then concatenate them along the third dimension.

```
allData = cell(numel(files), 1);
for i = 1:numel(files)
  fileTable = load(files(i).name);
  fileMat = table2array(fileTable);
  allData{i} = fileMat;
end
data = cat(3, allData{:});
```

Comment: Thanks but since not all data is scalar I prefer a cell.